# Sending a get variable to php file through getJSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

Is it possible to send a parameter (eg. a get variable) with getJSON to a php file, and if so how to do it?

The code below doesn't work, but hopefully it shows what I try to accomplish.

```
var url = "http://www.address.com/"

$.getJSON('http://anotheraddress.com/messages.php?url=+escape(url))', function(data) {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: The reason it's not working is because you've got the variable inside the string. Cut the string before your + character to solve it or use the second argument for data as suggested in some answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) accepts another parameter for data:

```
var url = "http://www.address.com/"

$.getJSON('http://anotheraddress.com/messages.php', { url: escape(url) }, function(data) {
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your jquery might look something like this

```
$.getJSON("messages.php", 
{
   data1: value1,
   data2: value2,
   url: escape(url)
},
function(data) { 
    alert(data.yourval);
});
```

The only thing you should remember while using getJSON is that, the php page `message.php` should return JSON string as a response. SO you have do something like this at the end of the file.

> echo json_encode($responseArray);
>   // Remember not to echo or output anything or the JQuery will not execute

Comment: He wants to send a variable to his php script from the js script, not the opposite ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your code to:

```
$.getJSON('http://anotheraddress.com/message.php?url='+escape(url), function(data) {
   // code here
});
```

Now you can access the `url` variable in your `message.php` file like this:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

Comment: is $url = $_GET['url'] really needed in the PHP file? Isn't it enough with $_GET['url']?

Comment: @JasonCraig - In your case, yes.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, a bad solution compared to what James Thorpe, Starx, and I proposed.

Comment: @Robin - And why is a bad idea? He wamted to know if he could send the url as in the request as get data, and I showed him how?

Comment: Because this is not the best way to send the data. What if you have 10 value to send? It's a lot cleaner to send a hash and let jquery do its thing (create the url for you).

Comment: @Robin - Agree with that, but still that wasn't the question.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question... `Is it possible to send a parameter with getJSON to a php file?`. We should show him the best way, even if it wasn't how he tried to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your data as the second parameter:
`jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )` ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/))

```
url = "http://www.address.com/"
$.getJSON({
  "http://anotheraddress.com/messages.php",
  { url: escape(url) },
  function(data) {}
})
```